# Appium iOS swipe is clicking

Tags: java, ios, selenium, appium, appium-ios

In attempt to swipe a conversation (to delete it) in the application, but Appium acts as clicking. I tried it on two devices with different variables for start and end position as well as duration. Here is the code:

```
driver.swipe(250,240,0,240,300);
```

Did anyone saw the same issue, if so, what was your solution?

I tried TouchActions with `press-wait-moveTo-release` as well as `longPress-moveTo-release` actions, but have the same result.
More over, I can tell that I can scroll up and down without an issue, but left to right and vise versa don't seem to work.

Some additional information:

- Appium 1.6.5 GUI or terminal
- java-client 5.0.0-BETA9
- selenium-java 3.3.0
- IntelliJ as IDE with Maven

Answer (score 3):

I use this code and its proven itself to me. It works for both iOS and Android.

It might be considered as deprecated, but for me it works, and I did not find any better solution.

```
public static void swipe(MobileDriver driver, DIRECTION direction, long duration) {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    int startX = 0;
    int endX = 0;
    int startY = 0;
    int endY = 0;

    switch (direction){
        case RIGHT:
            startY = (int) (size.height /2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            break;

        case LEFT:
            startY = (int) (size.height /2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            break;

        case UP:
            endY= (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            startY  = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);
            break;


        case DOWN:
            startY = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            endY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);

            break;

    }

    new TouchAction(driver)
            .press(startX, startY)
            .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
            .moveTo(endX, startY)
            .release()
            .perform();

}
```

`DIRECTION` is just an enum with values `UP, DOWN...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
new TouchAction(driver)
    .press(PointOption.point(500, 596))
    .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(1000)))
    .moveTo( PointOption.point(518, 478))
    .release()
    .perform();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

**Implementation method may look like this**

```
public void swipeScreen(String direction) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = Device.driver;
        HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<>();
        scrollObject.put("direction", direction);
        js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
    }
```

**Then call the above method using** (*Don't forget to declare String first* )

```
String DOWN="down";
String LEFT ="left";

swipeScreen(DOWN); //or swipeScreen(LEFT); ....likewise up and Right
```

Best reference at the [official web](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/#touchaction)